# Chrome on android - export tabs

Tags: android, google-chrome

I am have some tab fetish and normally open ~200 tabs on my phone and since time to time sort it...and do some clean up... As my phone died I was a victim of lost of all tabs as chrome tab sync is broken for ages...and can't sync more then 80 tabs properly... Therefore is there any file where chrome keeps list of open tabs? So I might be able to backup that file directly from phone storage some where using foldersync? That was Samsung S7.

Thank you.

Comment: i thought that android is opensource, seems these things are secret?

Comment: But Google Chrome for android is not opensource, which is probably why they closed it.